# Can't show svg when using html tag <svg> in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, svg

When I try to use SVG tag in HTML5 to create image, it seems it doesn't work! 
Code:
[image]
Result:
[image]
JSfiddle:
[image]

Original Code:

```
 <svg  id="svg4"  width="165" height="85">
 <rect x="3" y="3" rx="20" ry="20"  width="160" height="80" style="fill:purple;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:1;">
 </svg>
```

Can anyone help me find a plugin or recommend a method to let this svg tag be shown in the WordPress as the same as the Jsfiddle does!

Update:
**Finally, I figured it out by myself.**

Firstly, disable the visual editor in the wordpress. The process is Dashboard -> User -> my profile. Then click the checkbox and select disable!
This would make sure the svg tag would not be striped by the wordpress editor!
[image]

After that, if running the code, it shows:
[image]

We could notice that the editor  add br tags into the svg block! The magic is if I delete the br tags, it works! Obviously, the br tag is added by the editor since there are line feeds in the svg block! So I delete the space inside the code. Then I got this！
[image]

**Lesson --** If something appear abnormally, closely look the final html code rendered by browser!

===================Update====================
A few days ago, I also came across a similar bug. The css file inside the editor work unnormally.

The editor would automatically add

tag and let css lose functionality
[image: automatically add <p> tag and let css lose functionality]

Comment: [This thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/inline-svg-disappears-when-switching-between-editing-modes) any help?  WordPress has a white list of allowed tags; if you disable the rich text editor for a post they don't get stripped.  Alternatively you could add all SVG tags and attributes to the allowable list (with `tiny_mce_before_init`, as they've done for iframe [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/iframes-being-stripped-out)), but given the number of tags, the first option may be easier.

Comment: [This](http://www.leighton.com/blog/stop-tinymce-in-wordpress-3-x-messing-up-your-html-code) might help, but it seems a little risky allowing all tags

Comment: @Hobo Thanks, Hobo. However, I tested both: 1. disable the rich text editor 2. use the code from the first link you give. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Hobo Hi, Hobo, I figured it out finally. Thanks again！